# Why does Java use -D to indicate system properties?

Tags: java, language-design, semantics, flags

Why is the flag that indicates a System property in Java `-D`? Surely there is some semantics to this letter choice, but I can't guess what it is.

Comment: I guess it means `D`efine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is short for setting a system define.

"define" debug to yes

```
-Ddebug=yes
```

There is some historical context, as other compilers use similar flags.  For example, `gcc` uses `-D` to set a preprocessor define.

```
gcc -D debug=yes test.c
```

will compile test.c with a preprocessing environment where the preprocessor variable `debug` is set to `yes`.

Answer (score 3):

"defines" properties. Properties aren't arguments, so you'd need a special identifier anyway.